# Business day formula help

Tags: formula, date

The use case: I am trying to calculate a date that is 3 "Bank Business days" after the application create date. Which includes Saturday and not Sunday.

The Below Formula is taking into consideration both Saturday and Sunday.

How would I adjust this formula to account for Saturday and not Sunday.

```
CASE(
MOD(Application_Created_Date__c - DATE(1900, 1,7),7),

0, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3-1)/5)*2,

1, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3)/5)*2,

2, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3+1)/5)*2,

3, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3+2)/5)*2,

4, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3+3)/5)*2,

5, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + CEILING((3)/5)*2,

6, (Application_Created_Date__c) - IF(3>0,1,0) + 3 + CEILING((3)/5)*2,
null)
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Add 4 to any day where the next 3 days includes a Sunday.  (Case 0 is Sunday. Case 6 is Saturday.)

```
CASE( MOD(Application_Created_Date__c - DATE(1900, 1,7),7),
0, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3-1)/5)*2,
1, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3)/5)*2,
2, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3+1)/5)*2,
3, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3+2)/5)*2,
4, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 4 + FLOOR((3+3)/5)*2,
5, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 4 + CEILING((3)/5)*2,
6, (Application_Created_Date__c) - IF(3>0,1,0) + 4 + CEILING((3)/5)*2, null)
```

Comment: I have entered this formula and it is still counting Sunday. It's exactly how you have it.

Comment: CASE( 
MOD(Application_Created_Date__c - DATE(1900, 1,7),7), 
 0, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3-1)/5)*2, 
 1, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3)/5)*2, 
 2, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 3 + FLOOR((3+1)/5)*2, 
 3, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 1 + FLOOR((3+2)/5)*2, 
 4, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 2 + FLOOR((3+3)/5)*2, 
 5, (Application_Created_Date__c) + 2 + CEILING((3)/5)*2, 
 6, (Application_Created_Date__c) - IF(4>0,1,0) + 3 + CEILING((3)/5)*2, 
null)

Comment: Is it working for you now?